# Set same width for all spinners in BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, spinner

It is possible to set the width of spinner which is in a baseadapter class?

When a text is too long the other elements dissappear because the spinner takes almost all the width of the display. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property in the layout of your spinner. Just below the text view add below script:

```
    <View  
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="1dp" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the issue. Thanks